# How can I create a for loop which increments a number until it finds the one which's remainder is 0?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop

I have a function which is supposed to find the smallest common multiple of the provided parameters that can be evenly divided by both of them plus the ones in between them.

The array always consists of two numbers which can be not in a numerical order.

For example. A value of `[1, 3]` would return 6, or `[1, 5]` would be 60.

1. I understand that at first I need to find the minimum number and the maximum number in the array.
2. Then I have to put all of the numbers in range of the minimum and maximum numbers including both of them into an array.
3. And then I need to somehow create a for loop which increments a number until it finds the one which's remainder is 0 when it's divided by each of the numbers in the array.

The third part I understand, but don't know how to implement. Any help and tips would be much appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  let minNum = Math.min(...arr);
  let maxNum = Math.max(...arr);
  let mySeq = [];
  for(let i = minNum; i <= maxNum; i++){
    mySeq.push(i);
  }
  // stuck here
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How can `[1, 3]` return 6? the smallest common multiple is 1. Same for `[1, 5]` and 60

Comment: @Cid Because [1,3] represents the lcm for 1, 2, and 3. similarly, [1,5] is of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: actually you need to find the lcm which will be tough to do. Why can't you find the gcd and use the property lcm*hcf = num1*num2 that way you will able to find the lcm of the numbers in a range represented by [1, n]

Comment: You create an array of numbers between the min and max... Which has no use in my opinion. Create a loop where you collect al multiples with has as maximum the minum * maximum (guaranteed lower or this number). Then check those 2 arrays for the same data and get the smallest number.

Comment: Thanks @MadaraUchiha Looks like I really suck at math, I didn't know the lcm of 2 numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One functional approach.

```js
const range = ([min, max]) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) arr.push(i);
  return arr;
};
const gcd = (a, b) =>  !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
const lcm = (a, b) => (a * b) / gcd(a, b);

const smallestCommons = (arr) => range(arr).reduce((acc, cur) => acc = lcm(acc, cur), arr[0]);

console.log(smallestCommons([1, 3])); // 6
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 6])); // 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your idea, I could create a function like this

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  let minNum = Math.min(...arr);
  let maxNum = Math.max(...arr);
  let mySeq = [];
  for(let i = minNum; i <= maxNum; i++){
    mySeq.push(i);
  }
  // stuck here
  let smallestCommon = maxNum;
  let found = false;
  while(!found){
    var j;
    for(j = 0; j< mySeq.length; j++){
      if(smallestCommon % mySeq[j] != 0) break;
    }
    if(j == mySeq.length){
      found = true;
    }else{
      smallestCommon ++;
    }
  }

  return smallestCommon;
}

smallestCommons([1, 3]) //return 6
smallestCommons([1, 5]) //return 60
```

However, I think there is still better way of approaches for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As i am not JS person i can give you the pseudo code.

```
lcm = 1
list =[1,2,3]

for i in len(list)-1:
   lcm = lcm*list[i+1]/gcd(lcm,list[i+1])

print(lcm)
```

**provide we need to find lcm of the number from 1 to n**

else we will  need to initilize lcm with first two number of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this the code that works for your scenarios.

```
        let array = [1,5];

        let returnValFunction = (arr) => {
            try {
                let minNum = Math.min(...arr);
                let maxNum = Math.max(...arr);
                let returnVal = false;
                let i = 1;
                while (!returnVal) {
                    let divingNum = maxNum * i;
                    let checkVal = true;
                    for (let a = maxNum; a >= minNum; a--) {
                        console.log('a', a);
                        console.log(Number.isInteger(divingNum / a));
                        !Number.isInteger(divingNum / a) ? checkVal = false : '';
                    }
                    if (checkVal) returnVal = divingNum;            
                    i++;
                };
                return returnVal;
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }

        let consoleValue = returnValFunction(array);
        console.log('consoleValue', consoleValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

That was an interresting problem to solve. I solved it this way, but I'm sure there's better ways to go.

I first calculated the lmc between the 2 biggest numbers.

Then, I compared this number multiplied by 1, then 2, then 3 and so on, modulo the next lowest number (max number - 2) until I find 0 as result. I kept calculating then modulo (max number - 3) until (max number - n) = arr[0];

```js
function lcm(nb1, nb2)
{
    let i = 1;
    let j = 1;
  
    while (true)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            if ((nb1 * i) == (nb2 * j))
                return (nb1 * i);
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
 
function smallestCommons(arr)
{
    if (arr.length == 2)
    {
        biggestNumber = arr[1];
        if (biggestNumber > 2)
        {
            let biggestCommon = lcm(arr[1] - 1, arr[1]);
            let mul = 1;
            for (let num = biggestNumber - 2; num > arr[0]; --num)
                while (((biggestCommon * mul) % num) != 0)
                    ++mul;
            return (biggestCommon * mul);
        }
        else
            return (biggestNumber);
    }
}
 
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5]));
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 3]));
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 42]));
console.log(smallestCommons([7, 10]));
console.log(smallestCommons([4, 5]));
```